# runOnUiThread(new Runnable) is undefined in class which extends View

Tags: android, android-canvas

Here in this timer code runOnUiThread( new Runnable) is undefined in a class which extends view. Is this possible to use this code in  class which extends View.

```
 Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.invalidate;
        }
     });
 } 
}, 40);
```

Comment: it is a method of activity. If you are using the activity`s context to inflate your view, you can cast the view`s context to activity

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 4):

`runOnUiThread()` is a method on `Activity`. What you want here is `post()`, which is a method on `View` that schedules a `Runnable` to be run on the main application thread.

Another approach than yours, one with less overhead, is:

```
new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    view.invalidate();
    view.postDelayed(this, 40);
  }
}.run();
```

This avoids the background thread created using `Timer` and `TimerTask`. If you wish to cancel this later, either have the `Runnable` watch for some `boolean` data member to change, or hold onto the `Runnable` and use it with `removeCallbacks()` (another method on `View`).

Comment: But there is a problem I can't use postDelayed. Total time taken by postdelayed is : Time of execution + 40 milisec Am I correct? I want to finish my task within 40 miliseconds .

Comment: @user1844130: You could replace `40` with `40-howeverLongItTook`. Also, bear in mind that both `post()` and `runOnUiThread()` have their own delays, as they simply arrange for your `Runnable` to be run on the main application thread, and that will not happen instantaneously.